# Beta-PERT distribution shape parameters division by zero?

Tags: probability-theory

For some input values to a beta-PERT distribution, the mean equals the mode which results in a division by zero when calculating the shape parameters.

I've followed https://www.riskamp.com/beta-pert, among others. Here are the formulas for the mean and shape parameters that the beta distribution uses:

$$ \mu = \frac{ x_{min} + x_{max} + \lambda x_{mode} }{(\lambda + 2)} $$

$$ v = \frac{ ( \mu - x_{min} )(2 x_{mode}-x_{min}-x_{max}) }{(x_{mode}-\mu)(x_{max}-x_{min})} $$

$$ w = \frac{v(x_{max}-\mu)}{(\mu-x_{min})} $$

It's rather obvious that this can happen, for example when given [0,4] with mode 2.

I expect that I've just misunderstood something. It turns out to be difficult to google for though, hope you can help me. :-/

Comment: If you have $\mu = x_{mode}$ you also have $2 x_{mode}-x_{min}-x_{max} = 0$ so the expression for $v$ becomes $\frac00$. You can either use another expression, or you can slightly perturb $x_{mode}$ to avoid $\frac00$.

Comment: When $x_{mode}$ is halfway between $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$, you get $v=w=\dfrac{\lambda}{2}+1$ which is $3$ when $\lambda$ is the conventional $4$.

Comment: Thanks @Henry, that really helped! Now I don't understand how I couldn't see it myself. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be clearer if we substitute in $\mu$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
v & = & \frac{ ( \frac{ x_{min} + x_{max} + \lambda x_{mode} }{(\lambda + 2)} - x_{min} )(2 x_{mode}-x_{min}-x_{max}) }{(x_{mode}-(\frac{ x_{min} + x_{max} + \lambda x_{mode} }{(\lambda + 2)})(x_{max}-x_{min})} \\
& = & \frac{ ( x_{min} + x_{max} + \lambda x_{mode} - (\lambda + 2)x_{min} )(2 x_{mode}-x_{min}-x_{max}) }{((\lambda + 2)x_{mode}-(x_{min} + x_{max} + \lambda x_{mode})(x_{max}-x_{min})} \\
& = & \frac{ ( x_{min} + x_{max} + \lambda x_{mode} - (\lambda + 2)x_{min} )(2 x_{mode}-x_{min}-x_{max}) }{(2x_{mode} - x_{min} - x_{max})(x_{max}-x_{min})} \\
& = & \frac{x_{max} - x_{min} + \lambda (x_{mode} - x_{min})}{x_{max}-x_{min}} \\
& = & 1 + \lambda\frac{x_{mode} - x_{min}}{x_{max}-x_{min}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So in fact there is no division by zero.